# Xcode - Image and text (with different length) always placed center

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I want to show the user's current country with flag and name at the top, I want them centered as if it was one image. The problem I faces is that each name of country of course isn't equal in length. I want the text and image to always be centered, so the total width of the flag and name will vary with the length of the country name.

See images below to see what i mean visually - the white background is the width of the screen.

[image: When the user's country is the United States]

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: As a side note, having everything be justified (to the left) is a better style than centering, looks more consistent as your user scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy with Auto Layout. Embed the image and text inside another view. Add the following constraints:

- Fixed distance between the image and text.
- Top, Left, and Bottom of the image `0 pt` to the container view.
- Right side of the text `0 pt` to the container view.
- Container view centered horizontally in container
- Some constraint that defines the y-coordinate of the container view (depends on what you are trying to do - centered vertically, top distance to superview, etc).

Comment: I'm curious to know how this accounts for the length of text/width taken up by text?

Comment: The label calculates the text size and returns it from `-intrinsicContentSize`, which the layout engine feeds into the solver. The same thing happens with the image size, unless you explicitly set a size for the image views, but it’s usually better to use the native size of image assets so you don’t get scaling artifacts.